# CSS all sticks to the left using IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've created a web-application and been testing it up until now only on Chrome and Firefox.

When I try opening it in Internet Explorer and it seems all of my div's do not get positioned in the middle but all stick to the left side of the window.

what can i do to fix this?

In the beginning i had the same problem with chrome and firefox but after i added this:
`*{margin: 0px auto;}` to my CSS file it all seemed to center itself.

Comment: What is so horrible about the rule? What else would you like to know?

Comment: you centered **ALL** element on page. Because you are using asterix (*) .

Comment: Why do you need to set 0px? 

margin: auto; should take care of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example :

```
<body>
<div id="cont">
asdasd
</div>
</body>
```

And css :

```
#cont {
margin : 0 auto; // Normally centered #cont for Chrome, Firefox and IE
}
body {
text-align : center; // But for perfect centering, IE need this.
}
```

Because , if you set BODY's text-align to center , All div's (which inside of `<body>`) will centered in IE . And then, you have to set this div's text-align to left, manually . You can try

Comment: Since i have many classes this won't help because i would have to add this to them all. In addition the problem is not with the text align, but with the align of the whole div containing the text

Comment: if you set BODY's text-align to center , All div's (which inside of <body>) will centered in IE . And then, you have to set this div's text-align to left, manually . You can try.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a Internet Explorer hack and put the margins right and left as auto.
Such as:

```
html * div {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:600px;
}
```

Comment: `float: center;` does not exist.

Comment: Well you can try setting both margins left and right to auto and then setting a fixed width to your div. That should do the job. margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:600px;

Comment: I'm not sure were talking about the same thing. I've got many divs and divs inside divs using these classes. I'm looking for a quick fix for IE to show the page like chrome and firefox do

Answer (score 0):

If you have a div or other tag that you want centered on the page, you need to specify a width for it, and then using the margin rule center it. What IE needs to see, at least 8 to my understanding, is that the parent div be a width of 100%. So something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then the CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}

#myDiv {
    /* this will center horizontally only, i assumed that is what you wanted */
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
}
```